# filestream c# read data repeatedly

Tags: c#, filestream

am using filestream with file handle to communicate with USB HID Device
the Device Resend The Report (array of byte[64]) As It's Received.
receive method occurs in another thread that fires an event when reports is read ,,

Every attempt sends ONLY ONE "Report"
first attempt is Ok ,, 1 Report received but when i send again it reads it twice ! (is it available twice in the filestream ??) 
on the next attempt the event fires twice again !
after that it add it three times for the next 3 attempts

```
attempt 1  1 report received
attempt 2  2 reports received
attempt 3  2 reports received
attempt 3  3 reports received
attempt 4  3 reports received
attempt 5  3 reports received
attempt 6  4 reports received
attempt 7  4 reports received
```

any more reports sent cause 4 reports received 
is there ANY logical description for this ?

code:

```
private void WriteData(object Data)
    {
        byte[] data = Data as byte[];
        int bytesSent = 0;
        while (bytesSent < data.Length)
        {
            byte [] OutputReportBuffer = new byte[64];
            for (int i = 0; i < OutputReportBuffer.Length; i++)
                if (bytesSent < data.Length)
                {
                    OutputReportBuffer[i] = data[bytesSent];
                    bytesSent++;
                }
                else OutputReportBuffer[i] = 0;
            try
            {
                fileStream.Write(OutputReportBuffer, 0, OutputReportBuffer.Length);
                fileStream.Flush();
            }
            catch///deducted code
        }
    }
```

here where its received (separate thread that fires event when data is read)

```
private void ReadData()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (fileStream.Read(ReceivedDataBuffer, 0, ReceivedDataBuffer.Length) > 0)
                {
                    _Context.Send(o =>
                    {
                        if (DataReceived != null)
                            DataReceived(this, new DataReceivedEventArgs(ReceivedDataBuffer));
                    }, null);
                }
            }
            catch //deducted code
        }
}
```

Comment: Code please. Probably, you are not evaluating the result of Read.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: A wild guess would be that somewhere in your code you re-register the `DataReceived` handler whenever the `DataReceived` is raised. The once-registered handler is not being automatically unregistered on event raise, therefore after first raise the same handler is registered second time. The next occurrence of the event is handled twice, hence the results you get. It's consistent with the fact that each time the data is "received" one time more than previously.

Comment: How are you counting the number of reports sent vs received? You should change your output to do so when sending or receiving. Then check if you see `sent, received, sent, received, received`

Comment: Thank Everybody for helping ,, @Grx70 was right 
it's my very own mistake because on the test form i made a button to connect, add events and write which register the handle more than once . Thank you all and special thanks to Grx70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the return value of `Read` to find out how many bytes you actually got.

Comment: it's always ReceivedDataBuffer.Length (64) or it's just 0 
only those two results in my case

Comment: Then maybe it's a race condition. Is Send asynchronous? In any case the bug is not visible here and you'd need to post more code.

Comment: you where right i should add the whole code it was two bugs in the code and it's solved now in the comments of the question ,, thank you